# Understanding the query: Selecting the most expensive product for each store

Tags: sql

Learning SQL now and my tutor recently posted this problem along with his suggested query:

```
Store(sid, sname)  //sid primary key here
Product(pid, pname, price, sid)  //sid foreign key here
```

**Goal:** For each store, find its most expensive product

His suggested query is this:

```
SELECT sname, x.pname
FROM Store, Product x
WHERE Store.sid = x.sid and
x.price >=
ALL (SELECT y.price
FROM Store, Product y
WHERE Store.sid = y.sid)
GROUP BY sname;
```

I'm having some trouble understanding it:

- Why are instances for the product table created?
- And why is a product table instance `x` called and then compared to another product table instance `Y`? If its within the same store, shouldn't the two tables be of the same instance?

Thanks!

Comment: this is not an answer to your question, but if you just start to learn SQL, you should ask you tutor to teach you the [ansi syntax for joins](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-for-beginners-joins).

Comment: Having two instances means it's possible to filter out products that have max price... So price >= {instance2} price

Comment: The solution provided is not correct, I am sure it'll give this error `'x.pname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace the tutor.  You should only be learning proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  Commas have been obsolete in SQL for decades.

The query should look like:

```
SELECT s.sname, p.pname
FROM Store s JOIN
     Product p
     ON s.sid = p.sid AND
        p.price >= ALL (SELECT p2.price
                        FROM Product p2
                        WHERE p2.sid = s.sid
                       );
```

(Note that this fixes the the problem with the subquery as well.)

This also introduces table aliases, which make the query easier to write and to read.  *All* columns are qualified with the table name, which is a best practice.

What is this doing?  The outer query produces all the products and all stores.  Some of these have the highest price.

The `WHERE` clause is extracting these products.  How?  The subquery returns all prices for a given store.  The `>= ALL` is saying "get me all rows where the price is greater than or equal to all other prices in the store".

I think this would more commonly be written using an aggregation function:

```
SELECT s.sname, p.pname
FROM Store s JOIN
     Product p
     ON s.sid = p.sid AND
        p.price >= (SELECT MAX(p2.price)
                    FROM Product p2
                    WHERE p2.sid = s.sid
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be one change in the suggested query to provide expected result:

```
SELECT sname, x.pname
FROM Store, Product x
WHERE Store.sid = x.sid and
x.price >=
  ALL (SELECT y.price
  FROM Product y
  WHERE Store.sid = y.sid)
```

-- Removed the second instance of Store table that is not required

Two instances of product tables created and compared because:

- Two are different instances and both will not be same, since different alias given
- First instance is in select statement and will return all the products. Out of the results, to fetch only the product that has highest price, another instance of product table is used
- Note that in the second instance of the product table, Store.sid is compared and not the x.pid

Hope this helps